# How to specify opening hours for a TouristAttraction? Google’s SDTT gives a warning when using 'openingHours'

Tags: schema.org

I have a tourism website that contains popular parks, museums, temples, historical places and so on. All of them have some opening and closing time.

Now each of my categories has a type in [Schema.org](http://www.schema.org) except tombs, forts and world heritage sites (in shot historical places). So what I did is, wrote only `"TouristAttraction"` in the `"@type"` field.

Now the problem is [Google’s SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) is saying:

> The property openingHours is not recognized by Google for an object of type TouristAttraction.

as a warning in that case only.

So what type should I define for historical places so that I can also write their opening and closing timings without getting any warning from the  SDTT?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the property type as `OpeningHoursSpecification`

The property values could be
`closes` of type `time`
`dayOfWeek` of type `DayOfWeek` 
`opens` of type `time`
`validFrom` of type `DateTime`
`validThrough` of type `DateTime`

This should work. 
You can read more here: http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification

By the way have a look at [Qualifying content types](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-content) for Google's Structured Data. It says Google only supports Articles, Local Business, Music, Receipes, Reviews, TV & Movies, Videos, Products, JobPostings, PodCasts, Datasets, FactChecks etc. I am little unsure if Google will show the results on SERP for OpeningHoursSpecification. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The [`openingHours`](http://schema.org/openingHours) property is not defined for the [`TouristAttraction`](http://schema.org/TouristAttraction) type, so it makes sense that Google’s SDTT doesn’t recognize it.

But `TouristAttraction` defines an alternative:

- [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification)
- [`specialOpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/specialOpeningHoursSpecification) (for overwriting what got specified with `openingHoursSpecification`, e.g., for exceptions)

Both properties expect values of the type [`OpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification).

Comment: How do you show closed for certain days
Sunday is closed no hours need to show how do I display that openingHoursSpecification -> doesn't show any example

Comment: @jibingeorge: Please ask a separate question for this ([ask]).